# Writing raw bytes to iostream

Tags: c++, pointers, operators, iostream

I was working on my custom buffer and stream recently and got stuck at the fact that I can't call my stream's behaviour from a pointer to iostream.

```
template <int N>
std::iostream& myStream::operator<<(char (&rhs) [N])
{
    write(rhs, N);
    return *this;
}

myStream* pS = new myStream();
std::iostream& s = *pS;
char buf[5] = "ABCD";
s << buf;
```

I've overridden `operator<<` in my class but, as I imagine the `iostream`'s `operator<<` should be `virtual` in order for this to work, am I right? Is there a way to get past this?

**EDIT2:**

code to test `std::ostream::operator<<`, ibuf is a mutable vector, overflow method, as listed above.

```
int ByteBuffer::overflow(int c) {
    std::vector<char>* buf = ibuf__;
    buf->resize(buf->capacity() * 2.5);
    std::ptrdiff_t putDiff = pptr() - pbase();
    setp(buf->data(), buf->data() + putDiff, buf->data() + buf->capacity());
    if (c != EOF)
        return sputc(c);
    return -1;
}

mutable std::vector<char>* ibuf__;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ByteBuffer bb;
    iostream s(&bb);

    char buf[4] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
    s << buf;
    s << buf << (char)0;
    return 0;
}
```

As a result I can see that ibuf has `"ABCD!@#$ABCD!@#$"` inside the buffer, where `!@#$` stands for a random sequence of characters (but after both `ABCD`'s it's the same sequence). That's why I assume, it seeks `'\0'`.

Comment: The operator overload to [output strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) are not actually member functions.

Comment: And it's often better to create a new [streambuf class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) and use that when constructing ordinary streams. Let the standard classes handle the formatting, and you only the actual buffering and writing to whatever destination you want.

Comment: Finally, look at the [Boost iostreams library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html).

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use boost here. As for the rest, as I've already mentioned I created my custom buffer as well, but the standard iostream operators provide wrong format i.e. I need a different one

Comment: What is the format you want? Can't you use standard output manipulators to fix the format?

Comment: It needs to be raw binary format

Comment: Then you shouldn't overload the inserter for this. The `std::streambuf` will be fine. Can you give us an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: And? Have you looked at e.g. *any* file in a binary editor? *All* data is stored in a "raw binary format". Please be more specific, for example how should the single character `'A'` be stored? As the *text* `"01000001"`? As the binary byte `01000001` (e.g. hex `0x41` or the ASCII code for `'A'`)? And as told by @0x499602D2 you don't need to create a new stream class, writing the data to disk (stored in whatever format you want) is the job for the stream *buffer*.

Comment: It doesn't look like that `operator<<()` overload is needed at all.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It doesn't work without overloading it though

Comment: @mewa What do you mean by it doesn't work? By your question is sounds like `operator<<()` wasn't being called in the first place. Also, that is not an mcve. Give us a minmal program that we can run ourselves to reproduce the same behavior.

Comment: @0x499602D2 data is written to wrong position. I get the impression, that when using char arrays the std iostream `operator<<` looks for a terminating `\0`, and also doesn't write that 0, which, since I'm writing a byte stream is a valid value as well, so I can't discard it.

Comment: Are you sure it's calling `underflow()`? That member is called by input stream functions. `write()` calls `overflow()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72860/discussion-between-mewa-and-0x499602d2).